# Could the bcrypt-ruby binding be vulnerable?

Tags: cryptography, appsec, known-vulnerabilities, ruby

While developing a **Ruby on Rails** application using a commonly used authentication library named **devise**, I noticed from the prefix `$2a$` of the produced password hashes in the application database that it's using a bcrypt variant.

I read up about crypt and bcrypt on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29#Blowfish-based_scheme) and noticed that newer variants of bcrypt are supposed to produce a prefix of `$2y$` because a non-OpenBSD implementation by someone named Solar Designer had a "major security flaw" in 2011 and therefore it is unclear if the `$2a$` hashes were produced by a secure implemenation.

I found out that **devise** is using a C and Java binding named **bcrypt-ruby** which indeed bundles a [C-implementation](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/ext/mri/crypt_blowfish.c) copied from **John the Ripper** which is stated to be written by a Solar Designer. Now I'm wondering if this implementation may still vulnerable to this "major security flaw".

Can anyone bring light to this topic?

**Update:**

The [version history](http://cvsweb.openwall.com/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/Owl/packages/glibc/crypt_blowfish/crypt_blowfish.c) of the file at the crypt repository of the **John the Ripper** project, from which the file seems to have originated, may help answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you refer to has been corrected.  If you check out the [source on Github](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/ext/mri/crypt_blowfish.c) vs the [posted diff fix by Solar Designer](http://cvsweb.openwall.com/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/Owl/packages/glibc/crypt_blowfish/crypt_blowfish.c.diff?r1=1.9;r2=1.10), you can see that the sign-extension has been noted and corrected (lines 553 through 556).

Keep in mind that even though prefix $2a$ is not recommended, neither is $2x$ which simply states that the buggy implementation is being used -- albeit, now you know.  According to the Wikipedia entry, you want to ensure your hashes are prefixed with $2y$. However, this was not the original fix according to [Solar Designer's email noting the problem](http://lists.randombit.net/pipermail/cryptography/2011-June/000923.html).  That fix merely ensured that to REQUEST the buggy behaviour (for backward compatibility), you would explicitly use version prefix $2x$.  The original $2a$ was retained to produce NEW, CORRECT behaviour (see line 609).  Therefore, the code in ruby-bcrypt is correct, but you don't explicitly know it as per the recommendations in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 5):

As announced on [openwall](http://www.openwall.com/lists/announce/2011/06/21/1), this bug was related to non-ASCII characters with the 8th bit set:

> *What's worse, in some cases (but not in all) one, two, or three
>   characters immediately preceding the 8-bit characters were ignored by
>   the password hash computation.  Thus, many passwords containing
>   characters with the 8th bit set are significantly easier to crack than
>   it was previously expected.*

If you read the README of bcrypt-ruby there is a note which addresses this issue.

> *Note: JRuby versions of bcrypt-ruby <= 2.1.3 had a security vulnerability that was fixed in >= 2.1.4. If you used a vulnerable version to hash passwords with international characters in them, you will need to re-hash those passwords. This vulernability only affected the JRuby gem.*

This is clarified [here](http://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/internat.adv):

> *Versions of jBCrypt before 0.3 suffered from a bug related to character
>   encoding that substantially reduced the entropy of hashed passwords
>   containing non US-ASCII characters. An incorrect encoding step
>   transparently replaced such characters by '?' prior to hashing. In the
>   worst case of a password consisting solely of non-US-ASCII characters,
>   this would cause its hash to be equivalent to all other such passwords
>   of the same length.*

Thus, since it has been fixed in the jRuby version of the library, i'd guess it's fixed in the MRI version as well.